# What are the required AzureAD Directory Roles For Assigning Application Roles on Enterprise Apps?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-security

**I am trying to figure out the exact Azure Active Directory - Directory Role, that will allow the assignment of Application Roles to an AD Group, on and Enterprise app**

The least Priviledge the better, as Global Admin is wide open

I am using the command "New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment" successfully in certain tenant / aad environments, but in others I get the below error.

**Error:**

```
New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment : Error occurred while executing NewGroupAppRoleAssignment
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
At line:49 char:11
+           New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $adGroup.Object ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment], ApiException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.Client.ApiException,Microsoft.Open.AzureAD16.PowerShell.NewGroupAppRoleAssignment
```

Through testing, I have confirmed that the "Global Administrator" AAD Directory Role, allows me to set the approle assignments on the Enterprise app, to an AD Group

**I will not have access to the "Global Administrator" Role in my dev/prod environments**

Is there a Custom Role I can create (or pass on to the AAD Directory Admins), to allow either Global Administrator, or some other role that actually works, **to the specific Enterprise Applications I will need to the Assign Roles to?**

I also tried the "Application Adiministrator" Directory role, which in documentation seems to fit, but I get the same "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" error

If a directory Custom Role conditional is possible, I would like to create it via Powershell

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the exact answer to my question at the following link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Azure-Active-Directory-now-with-Group-Claims-and-Application/ba-p/243862

Application Roles:
The global administrator or the user administrator of an Organization can assign users and groups to applications in Azure AD

Answer (score 1):

The `Application Adiministrator` does not have the privilege to do that, except the `Global Administrator`, you need a least privileged role named `Privileged role administrator` to manage role assignments.

See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/roles-delegate-by-task#roles-and-administrators):

[image]

For more details about the AAD directory role, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I just gave it a shot. The "Privileged role administrator", although looking promising, does not allow me to assign application roles to the Enterprise apps, via New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment. So the question is, what kind of custom role could be created to allow a user to assign application roles to an enterprise app, with out giving them "Global Admin" across the whole subscription. Can you grant Global Admin to a user, for a specific Enterprise app, as the "Resource"?

Comment: @Gvazzana Not understand your requirement, if you want to assign role to enterprise app(service principal), you may use this command [New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadserviceapproleassignment?view=azureadps-2.0)? I think `New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment` assigns the role to the group.

Comment: Correct, I am assigning application roles from the registered app's manifest,  to an aad group, on the enterprise application. These application roles represent our web app's permissions, so that users inside the aad group, will receive the specified application roles. So I am trying to figure out how I can make a more "least priviledge" oriented custom aad role, other then Global Amdinistrator. This role would permit me to make the application role assignments I desire in an AAD that I cannot have Global Admin rights in

Comment: I think I may have found the exact answer to my question at the following link: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Azure-Active-Directory-Identity/Azure-Active-Directory-now-with-Group-Claims-and-Application/ba-p/243862    .“Global Administrators” and “User Administrators” can assign roles for users or groups

Comment: @Gvazzana Per my test, I can use `Application Adiministrator` to run `New-AzureADGroupAppRoleAssignment`.